How to add the below given logic in the PL/SQL view?
From this query, when we will select these three attributes,
SELECT
d.docfg_storage_cat,
d.docfg_ph_objid,
d.docfg_filename
FROM
(
SELECT
SUBSTR(a1.dradg_objky,4,11) doc_no,
a1.auspg_atwrt package_name
FROM v_doo_ausp a1
WHERE a1.drawg_dokar = 'MAT'
AND a1.auspg_atwrt = 'PG-DSO-8-3'
AND a1.AUSPG_ATNAM = 'R_PACKAGE'
AND a1.KSSKG_CLASS = 'R_PACKAGE'
AND a1.DRADG_OBJKY LIKE 'POL%'
),
v_doo_ausp a2,
v_doo_draw_files d
WHERE a2.DRADG_DOKNR = doc_no
AND a2.DRAWG_DRAT_DKTXT = 'PACKAGE OUTLINE'
AND d.dradg_doknr = a2.dradg_doknr
AND d.dradg_objky = a2.dradg_objky
ORDER BY d.drawg_dokvr;

Then using this condition we will generate the link -
if (d.docfg_storage_cat?.StartsWith("Y") == true)
  return @$"http://example.com/contRep=Y_COMPASS_PROD&docId={d.docfg_ph_objid}&compId={d.docfg_filename}";
else
  return @$"http://example.com/contRep=Z_COMPASS_PROD&docId={d.docfg_ph_objid}&compId={d.docfg_filename}";

How will we code this logic to add the attribute for generated link (for eg.LINK_TO_DRAWING) in the below given view:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_PACKAGE2REALIS AS
WITH V_DEAL_INFO AS (
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT delv_id,
                 pk_package_name,
                 pk_package_lead_a,
                 pk_package_lead_b,
                 pk_standoff,
                 pk_standoff_uom,
                 pk_id
            FROM packages,
                 dprd_element_vers
           WHERE delv_element_version_id = pk_id
             AND delv_dtbl_id = (SELECT dtbl_id
                                   FROM dprd_tables
                                  WHERE dtbl_table_name = 'PACKAGES')) main_tbl
      
   WHERE dlpp_tn IS NOT NULL
     AND dsob_tn IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
       DISTINCT pt.pktc_technology,
       pf.pfam_package_family,
       pc.pkcl_package_class,
       pg.pkgp_package_group,
       W_DEAL_INFO.DSOB_BALL_DIAMETER_UOM,
       W_DEAL_INFO.DSOB_BALL_DIAMETER
FROM package_technologies pt,
     package_families pf,
     package_classes pc,
     package_groups pg,
     packages pack,
     W_DEAL_INFO
WHERE pack.pk_pkgp_id = pg.pkgp_id
  AND pg.pkgp_pkcl_id = pc.pkcl_id
  AND pc.pkcl_pfam_id = pf.pfam_id
  AND pf.pfam_pktc_id = pt.pktc_id
  AND pack.pk_id = W_DEAL_INFO.pk_id(+)
;


I am expecting to add a new attribute LINK_TO_DRAWING in the package2realis view and add the logic under it in pl/sql to generate that link.

??? MySQL does not support PL/SQL. Adjust your tags list. Specidy precise DBMS name and version.
